# My method and function are not working in array of array

Tags: javascript, function, oop, multidimensional-array, methods

I have a 2d array, which is a board for a game. I have created some objects players, weapons etc which are also held in their own arrays.
So far this is fine. I can create the objects update their properties etc.

What I'm trying to now do create some methods and functions for the game. Eg; a player picking up the weapon and have the properties updated to show this.

I have tried these methods in a single array and it worked, as soon I made it an array or arrays I have had trouble.

```
class Player {
  constructor(name, players, hp) {
    this.name = name;
    this.players = players;
    this.hp = 100;
    this.currentWeapon = null;
  }
  pickUp(weapons) {
    this.currentWeapon = weapons;
    weapons.hold = true;
    weapons.player = this;
  }
  dropOff(weapon) {
    this.currentWeapon = null;
    weapon.hold = false;
    weapon.player = null;
  }


  class Weapon {
    constructor(name, id, damage, weapons) {
      this.name = name;
      this.id = id;
      this.damage = damage;
      this.weapons = weapons;
      this.player = null;
      this.hold = false;
    }
  }


  players.pickUp(weapons);
  players.dropOff(weapons);
```

I basically want the currentWeapon to update as well as the this.player and this.hold properties when the function is called.

I have each class stored as their own array as well.

When I run it it either says XXX is not a function or XXX is not defined.

The players and weapons are on an array of an array which is the board.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: "*as soon I made it an array or arrays I have had trouble.*" can you provide an example? There is no difference in how code works when items are stored in a flat array or multi-dimensional array. It seems there is a bug in your implementation but it's hard to say what it might be.

Comment: beware that you're passing a **single reference** of weapons, hence if the reference is altered somewhere else, the Player's class instance property **will be altered as well**. You should make a shallow / deep copy if `weapons` or a new weapon instance if you want to make it "unique".

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess is somewhere in your code you have something like:

```
const players = []
players.push(new Player(...))  // in a for loop
```

If that's the case and if you expect an array of players to have a method pickUp, that's your issue.
Each player object has a pickup method not players (array of Player).

Possible solution:

```
players.forEach(player => player.pickUp(weapons));
players.forEach(player => player.dropOff(weapons));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty hard to tell without seeing the full code. The error you are experiencing is because the *call site* is
incorrect. When calling a method using `obj.method()`.

From what I see in your code all of your methods are unbounded, meaning their lexical context depends on their *call site*,
calling `obj.method()` will bound the `this` (lexical context) to `obj`. An invalid call site (calling `obj.method()`
when `obj` resolves to `null` for instance) can have several origins:

- out of bound error when looking up the arrays
- getting references to the unbounded method and then calling it: `var method = obj.method; method()` will throw if
  `method` uses `this` (as it is now `undefined`).